# Extracting 2nd occurrence of a number in parenthesis

Tags: formulas, regex, google-sheets

I have the following text string in Google Sheets, `DV2`:

```
Share Price vs. Fair ValueBelow Fair Value: AAPL ($126.85) is trading above our estimate of fairvalue ($118.02)Significantly Below Fair Value: AAPL is trading above ourestimate of fair value.
```

From this value, I want to extract the second number in parenthesis: `118.02`

My formula:

```
=iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(DV2;"\((.*)\)([A-Z,a-z,$])"))
```

The formula returns two columns:

| $118.02 | S |
| --- | --- |

I want to get rid of the column with the `S` and also the `$` before the number.

I tried using  [regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) to solve it but was unsuccessful.

Is there a way to modify the REGEXEXTRACT formula so it returns a single value without the `$`?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the 2nd value

In `B1`, enter the formula :

```
=-LOOKUP(1,-RIGHT(LEFT(A1,MATCH(1,-INDEX(MID(A1,ROW($1:$250),1),0))),ROW($1:$250)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taken that the cell in question is `DV2`, you can use the following formula

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(DV2;".*\$(.+)\)")
```

If you want to turn the result to an actual number add `^1` at the end of the formula.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(DV2;".*\$(.+)\)")^1
```

If you need to, you can also add the `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(DV2;".*\$(.+)\)")^1)
```